# merge two folder structures - batch script of vbs

Tags: batch-file, merge, directory

I need a script to merge two folder structures:
folder structure 1:
\192.168.1.1\db\Docs\A 001
\192.168.1.1\db\Docs\A 002
\192.168.1.1\db\Docs\A 003
etc

folder structure 2:
\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\A 001
\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\A 002
\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\A 003
etc

what i need to do is:
1. under "\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\A 001" create subfolder **Docs**
2 then move folder (with its content) \docs\a 001  to \RAW\Docs\A 001
and the same thing to the remaining folders

the end result would be:
\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\A 001\Docs\A 001

Any one can help here? Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple

```
move \\192.168.1.1\db\Docs \\192.168.1.1\db\RAW\
```

would suffice?

Following your answer:

```
robocopy folder1 folder2 /e /copyall /xc /xn /xo
robocopy folder2 folder1 /e /copyall /xc /xn /xo
```

See `robocopy /?` to see what exclusion switches suit you better. You might have files that differ by content if they have the same name.

Comment: each folder structure contains approx 2000 sub-folders

Comment: @Andre: I am sorry, I am not sure that I understand what you want really…

Comment: there are two separate folder structures: [link](http://www.box.net/shared/6r6byixcti) i need to merge them into one

Comment: i know how to copy files using DOS commands, what i'm looking for is a script with a loop that would go through the folders and do this for me. As i said there are few hundreds of folders to process, doing it one by one is out of the question.

Comment: @Andre: robocopy is recursive. Just run it on the parent folder.